# Implementing the A(:,k)=b; Matlab-like syntax in a C++ matrix library: avoiding const-ness

Tags: c++, class, expression, template-meta-programming

I have developed an expression templates-based C++ matrix class of my own. I have also implemented a `Range` class to enable Matlab-like reads as

```
cout << A(Range(3,5),Range(0,10)) << endl;
```

I would now like to enable Matlab-like assignments as

```
A(Range(3,5),Range(0,10))=B;
```

where `B` is an appropriate matrix.

The `Matrix` `()` operator overload is as follows

```
inline Expr<SubMatrixExpr<const OutType*,OutType>,OutType> operator()(Range range1, Range range2)
{   typedef SubMatrixExpr<const OutType*,OutType> SExpr; 
    return Expr<SExpr,OutType>(SExpr(...some stuff...),...some stuff...); 
}
```

The `SubMatrixExpr` class is exemplified as

```
template <class A, class Type>
class  SubMatrixExpr
{
    // Constructor (M is a pointer to the Matrix data)
    SubMatrixExpr(const A &M, ...stuff...) : ...stuff...    

    // Access operator
    inline Type operator[](const int i) const { ...stuff... }
}
```

while the `Expr` class is exemplified as follows:

```
template <class A, class B>
class Expr
{
    // Constructor (a is the expression, the SubMatrixExpr in my case)
    Expr(const A &a, ...stuff...) : ...stuff...

    // Access
    inline B operator[](const int i) const { return a_[i]; }

    Expr<A,B> operator=(const Matrix<B> &ob)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<GetNumElements(); i++) { std::cout << a_[i] << " " << ob.GetDataPointer()[i] << "\n"; a_[i] = ob.GetDataPointer()[i]; }
        return *this;
    }
}
```

My problem is the following. I use `const` in the access operators for the two expression classes above. The result is that the overloaded `=` operator of the `Expr` class correctly returns `a_[i]` and `ob.GetDataPointer()[i]`, but it does not make the assignment.

Is it possible to disregard the `const`-ness within the overloaded `=` operator without having the change the entire code?

Thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT following Lol4t0's answer**

I have removed my original access operator for the `Expr` class and added

```
inline const B& operator[](const int i) const { return a_[i]; }
inline  B& operator[](const int i)  
{ 
    const Expr& constThis = *this;
    return const_cast<B&>(constThis[i]); 
}
```

Also, I have removed my original access operator for the `SubMatrixExpr` and added

```
inline const Type& operator[](const int i) const
{
    // Stuff
    return M_[IDX2R(GlobalRow,GlobalColumn,Columns_up_)];
}
```

and

```
inline Type& operator[](const int i) 
{
    // Stuff
    // The following line returns an error
    return M_[IDX2R(GlobalRow,GlobalColumn,Columns_up_)];
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler returns the following error

```
qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "LibraryNameSpace::double2_ &" to initializer of type "const LibraryNameSpace::double2_"
```

(`double2_` is a complex type of my own).

**EDIT #2 - Information on M_**

```
template <class A, class Type>
class  SubMatrixExpr
{
    private:
   A M_;

    // STUFF
}
```

From the `Matrix ()` operator overload reported above, `A = const OutType*`, where `OutType` is the matrix type, `double2_` for the example I'm currently running.

Comment: What is `M_` here? How is it defined?

Comment: Added information on `M_` in the edited post. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, but if `A` is `const OutType*`, then `_M` elements cannot be modified at all, as they are of constant type.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Yes, I have now removed the `const` keyword and now everything seems to work. But could I still use the `const` keyword and have a mean to circumvent the `const`-ness within the overloaded `[]` operator so that I should not change the existing code? Again, thanks and I have accepted your answer :-)

Comment: You should anyway return by reference, and you can use `const-cast`, but _very carefully_. Because modifying _really constant_ value is _undefined behavior_! I don't think you have lot of code, and I think you'd better fix it now, otherwise you may _have to_ fix it later, and it would be more complex, than now.

Comment: Have you completely implemented your matrix? Is it open source? Can I use it in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually not the constenss problem. You return *by value* in your `operator []`'s. So, the returned value gets copied and you assign new value to the copy, that gets destroyed.

Actually, your code works like this

```
struct S
{
    int v;
} x = {0};
S foo() { return x;}
int main() 
{
    foo() = {1}; 
    std::cout << foo().v;
}
```

Of cause, it will not save new value, that you assigned.

Usually containers have 2 overloads of `operator[]`:

- The first overload operates on constant container and it returns by *constant reference*.

  ```
  const Type& operator[](const int i) const { ...stuff... }
  const B& operator[](const int i) const { return a_[i]; }
  ```
- Second overload works with mutable container and returns *by reference*, so container items could be modified:

  ```
  Type& operator[](const int i) { ...stuff... }
  B& operator[](const int i) { return a_[i]; }
  ```

In principle, mutable version can be implemented through constant one:

```
B& Class::operator[](const int i) 
{
const Class& constThis = *this;
return const_cast<B&>(constThis[i]);
}
```

Comment: do you ever actually use const_cast to implement the mutable version? I never do, so I write two versions of the function (one const, one mutable) every time.. and every time I find it annoying. But I've never resorted to using const_cast -- just feels wrong. :)

Comment: @Corey, if getter is short, I write two functions. And getters _are_ usually short. But if getter would be non-trivial, I'll use `const_cast`.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Thank you very much for your answer. I have fixed my code according to your recommendations, as reported in the edited post. Unfortunately, the compiler returns an error (see edited post). Do you have indications on why? Again, thanks.